# Android XML File

Tags: android

I am trying to build a real estate app. I am having the following problem. I am trying to run this in the Android Studio but i seem to get error that I am missing a required attribute height and width. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I will be very thankful.

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.estate"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
                android:name="com.example.estate.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Registration Activity -->
        <activity
                android:name=".RegActivity"
                android:label="User Registration" >
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".ScreenActivity"
                android:label="Welcome::" >
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".NewPropertyActivity"
                android:label="Post a property/holding" >
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".AllProductsActivity"
                android:label="Available Properties" >
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".EditProductActivity"
                android:label="Property Details" >
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".MessageActivity"
                android:label="Talk to the Admin" >
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".ReadComments"
                android:label="Property" >
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".AddComment"
                android:label="Property" >
        </activity>

    </application>

    <!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: The error is most likely in your layout XML file, not the AndroidManifest.xml file that you posted here.

Comment: As @Code-Guru said the error is probably in one of your layouts. Most likely a `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height` tag is missing from a `View`. Please edit the layout of the `Activity` or `Fragment` where you get the error into your question.

Comment: Share the code from your XML file.